# gstreamer transcoding with wavparse and vorbisenc fails

Tags: gstreamer

I can play this wav :

http://freewavesamples.com/yamaha-sy35-clarinet-c5

```
gst-launch filesrc location=Yamaha-SY-35-Clarinet-C5.wav ! wavparse ! autoaudiosink
```

So I assume that wavparse is functioning properly, but 
this pipeline fails to transcode :

```
gst-launch filesrc location=Yamaha-SY-35-Clarinet-C5.wav ! wavparse ! vorbisenc ! filesink location=out.ogg
```

with the following warnings and errors

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.028608695 23692       0xa99720 WARN                wavparse gstwavparse.c:2110:gst_wavparse_loop: error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.028637670 23692       0xa99720 WARN                wavparse gstwavparse.c:2110:gst_wavparse_loop: error: streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstwavparse.c(2110): gst_wavparse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Strangely, the error is occuring in wavparse, so it is fine 
when the pipeline ends with an audio device sink, but not with an encoding sink...

Answer (score 1):

try this pipeline:
gst-launch filesrc location=audio.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! filesink location=out.ogg

I think the format it doesn't supported in vorbisenc example (audio/x-raw-float) vorbisenc support (audio/x-raw-int), that why you should add audioconvert. You can see all details if you add -v option in your pipeline.

Comment: This solves the error message, and an out.ogg file is created with 59714 bytes, but it seems invalid, because it won't play. I ran the command "oggz info out.ogg", and it prints Content-Duration: 00:00:00.000.   "oggz validate out.ogg" prints : Error: File contains no Ogg packets. Note the pipeline gives the warning : WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2395:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<pipeline0> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.000000000

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me too, it lacks a `! oggmux` so pipeline should be `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=out.ogg`